Dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Windows 11 without any bootloader
Is it a good idea to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and windows 11 without any bootloader like grub ? .
I asked this question because each of the time during an update (especially firmware update , bios update) the system needs to restart, and during the restart the system goes into GRUB , and most of the time the update remains incomplete.
So by not installing any bootloader, anytime i restart from ubuntu i land up in ubuntu, and restart from windows lands in windows and the update will be completed. The only con is that i will need to press the key to go to temporary boot each time i switch on the laptop, or it will boot according to priority. Is that right , or is there any disadvantages of doing so?
Please forgive if it's a silly question, i have seen questions similar to it, but not the exact one , I'm asking because the laptop is that much important to me and I can't afford messing it up ,
Thanks for your responses

You have to have a boot loader. You can set in UEFI settings one system as default and interrupt UEFI boot with f12 or whatever your system uses to choose another install. And you can set grub to default boot into any system and choose alternative from grub menu when desired. You cannot interrupt UEFI update without major breakage. But what you describe is a typical Windows update that has to reboot, sometimes multiple times to finish update. Ubuntu only needs reboot with a kernel or kernel related update.

To the file /etc/default/grub, add the lines:
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

Then the grub boot will default to the last selection booted, so your Windows reboots will go to Windows, and after you select Ubuntu to boot, Ubuntu will be the new default boot.
